# How to filter the two next rows in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list of values like that:

```
  var PLANNING_3D_RESP = [
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'En cours', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP']
]
```

And when I encounter the value "Terminé", I would like to filter (delete) the 2 next rows, so the result would look like that :

```
  var PLANNING_3D_RESP = [
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'En cours', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
]
```

So I have try to understand a bit better the [.filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) method, but it didn't help me that much.

Here is the code I did so far to filter the two next lines after the "Terminé" value.

```
function myFunction() {
  var PLANNING_3D_RESP = [
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'En cours', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP']
]
  

  var PLANNING_3D_CLEAN = PLANNING_3D_RESP;
  for (let i = 0; i < PLANNING_3D_CLEAN.length; i++) {
    if (PLANNING_3D_RESP[i][5] == "Terminé") {
      PLANNING_3D_RESP.filter(i => 1 + i);
      PLANNING_3D_RESP.filter(i => 2 + i);

    }
  }


Logger.log (PLANNING_3D_RESP)
Logger.log (PLANNING_3D_CLEAN)
```

What's wrong with it ?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly guess your situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

From your showing sample input and output values, I thought that your values might have regularity. If my understanding is correct, how about splitting `PLANNING_3D_RESP` every 3 elements? When this is reflected in your sample input and output values, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
var PLANNING_3D_RESP = [
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'En cours', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP']
];

var res = [...Array(Math.ceil(PLANNING_3D_RESP.length / 3))].map((_) => PLANNING_3D_RESP.splice(0, 3)).flatMap(e => e[0][5] == "Terminé" ? [e[0]] : e);
console.log(res);
```

#### Modified script 2:

As another modification, how about the following modification?

```js
var PLANNING_3D_RESP = [
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'En cours', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'Terminé', true, 'durée projet'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAT'],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, 'BK', true, 'date BAP']
];

var res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < PLANNING_3D_RESP.length; i++) {
  res.push(PLANNING_3D_RESP[i]);
  if (PLANNING_3D_RESP[i][5] == "Terminé") {
    i += 2;
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

When these scripts are run, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  ["Scénographie",true,true,true,true,"Terminé",true,"durée projet"],
  ["Plan tactile",false,false,false,false,"En cours",true,"durée projet"],
  ["Plan tactile",false,false,false,false,"BK",true,"date BAT"],
  ["Plan tactile",false,false,false,false,"BK",true,"date BAP"],
  ["Maquette tactile bâtiment",false,false,false,false,"Terminé",true,"durée projet"]
]
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)